# count features in polygon shapefile A that fall within each feature of polygon shapefile B

Tags: polygon, grass-gis, intersection, overlay

I have two polygon shapefiles, each of which contain multiple (possibly overlapping) polygons.

Is there some way, using GRASS, to calculate the number of polygons belonging to shapefile A that fall within each of the polygons that exist in shapefile B? Preferable would be a method that doesn't require rasterization, but I'm open to going down that route if necessary.

(I'm aware that this can be done in R, using the `over()` function, but these are large files I'm referring to, and so I'd prefer to do it in GRASS.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To continue webrian's suggestion:

```
v.select ain=poly_a b_in=poly_b oper=within out=a_within_b
```

Now the output vector "a_within_b" will contain those polygons from a that were **totally** within b.
But be careful: when you import a shapefile into GRASS with overlapping polygons, the overlaps will be split up by the topology "clean" operation, so you'll have more, smaller polygons in the GRASS vector than in the original shapefile.

Now to count the number of polygons, you might (depending on the database GRASS is using) be able to do:

```
echo 'SELECT count(cat) FROM a_within_b' | db.execute
```

But this raises the question: why not do this right in a spatial database from the start? Import both shapefiles into spatialite, and run:

```
SELECT count(poly_a.pk_uid) FROM poly_a, poly_b 
WHERE ST_Within(poly_a.Geometry, poly_b.Geometry);
```

Comment: I tried out spatialite and it seems like a viable option. I was interested in identifying the features of A (or their count) that occurred within (incl. crossing, etc.) each of the features of B, I ended up using: `SELECT polyA.pk_uid AS pk_A, polyB.pk_uid AS pk_B
  FROM polyA, polyB 
WHERE ST_Intersects(polyB.Geometry, polyA.Geometry)
    AND polyB.ROWID IN
    (
     SELECT pkid FROM idx_polyB_Geometry
     WHERE pkid MATCH RTreeIntersects
    (
      MBRminX(polyA.geometry),
      MBRminY(polyA.geometry),
      MBRmaxX(polyA.geometry),
      MBRmaxY(polyA.geometry)
   ));` Comments?

Comment: The above still seems quite slow (although maybe my expectations are too high...). Can anyone see a way to speed this up?

Comment: If you're using a recent version of spatialite, then the format for adding a spatial index to the "WHERE" clause is simpler: ...AND polyB.ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID FROM SpatialIndex WHERE f_table_name='polyB' AND search_frame=polyA.Geometry);   Maybe that will speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [v.select](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.select.html) module in GRASS GIS. There is no need to rasterize.

Comment: Thanks webrian, but I can't quite figure out how to use it for my purposes... I get the feeling it just returns those features in `ainput` that overlap with features of `binput` (overlap is the default, and apparently the only option available without GEOS, which I haven't yet worked out how to use with GRASS via R). I will try directly from GRASS though, to see whether there might be more to it than I realise. Can you provide an additional info re how to invoke v.select?

Comment: I would love this to be the answer, but I think v.select compares all features from each layer at the same time, not each feature separately. For that, it (probably) needs to be used with v.extract first.